# Web Server (Apache) Rewrites on NGINX

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, nginx, apache

I'm planning to use NGINX rather than Apache as my webserver on my next Magento project and am wondering about the **Use Web Server (Apache) Rewrites** on the Magento installer wizard?

[image]

1. What exactly do Web Server Rewrites do? I believe they just remove
   the index.php from the url? How important are they?
2. Should this option be checked when using NGINX? Do Magento Web
   Server Rewrites work with NGINX

Comment: while this is your dev site i suggest you to go ahead as is and test it, you will see whats going on eventually... more you click and try - faster you will learn, you can change these settings in magento admin panel, afterall

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your questions:

**1. What exactly do Web Server Rewrites do? I believe they just remove the index.php from the url? How important are they?**

Correct, the remove the `index.php` for the URL to give you pretty URLs. Most modern websites and shops use them and I would recommend to do so.

**2. Should this option be checked when using NGINX? Do Magento Web Server Rewrites work with NGINX**

Yes, it's a setting that Magento uses to generate the URLs in a certain way. However, since the Apache rewrites don't work on NginX you'll need to replace the `.htaccess` with some NginX configuration which is located, probably, in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/[domain].conf`

Check out the [Magento Wiki](https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento) and this [Github page](https://github.com/magenx/nginx-config/blob/master/magento/nginx.conf) for examples.